# Multipile queries vs a long query with joins in my situation

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, join, query

I am currently working on a project where, each user can possess multipile portfolios. Each portfolio contains products, each product contains assets, which can be associated to different kinds that have little to no resemblances between them, and each asset can have additional input created by a specific user.

Users can also share portfolios with other users, and products can be associated to multipile portfolios, incase a user wants to create a portfolio with the same product again, for selective sharing.

That essentially means that there is a many to many connection between users and portfolios, many to many connection between portfolios and accounts, one to many connection between accounts and assets, and one to many connection between assets and user input.

As of now, things are being connected through junction tables. That means that there are foreign keys selectively, in the users and portfolios table, portfolios and accounts table, accounts and multipile different assets table (multipile foreign keys where some are often null per row), and user inputs and multipile different asset tables (multipile foreign keys where some are oftne null per row).

I have eliminated the need to fetch all portfolios at once, as the plan is to pull a list of all portfolio ids and only fetch specific data of a specific portfolio at a time.

Thus, I have a query that fetches right away from the portfolio -> products junctions table, that joins with the products table, then joins with the product -> assets junction table, and then, there is a dilemma.

On one hand, I could fetch the requested assets from all tables through a left join each time, but that would obviously be very inefficient and would waste alot of memory.

On another hand, I could just go for multipile requests where I fetch each time until I get to the products -> assets junction table and then selectively pick an asset type from one of the asset table types each time, fetch the associated data, and then go for the associated user input table that is connected to the specific picked assets.

Currently, both are working very fast, as there isn't alot to fetch from. However, obviously, there can be scalability issues, and I am not entirely sure what could be ideal in the current situation in the "longer" run.

Keep in mind, I cannot streamline the different assets tables structure as they are way too different to begin with. However, I am requested to associate the different types into the same portfolio.

I would really appreciate some help/insights, thanks in advance! :)
**The database is postgresql, version 15**

The one that fetches from multipile asset types at once (less than ideal, there is no correlation between y_assets and x_assets, and keep in mind that's just an example, there may be even more different asset table types later on).

```
`create or replace function fetch_data(identifier int)
returns setof record language sql as $$
SELECT products.id as product_id, x_assets.*, y_assets.*, user_assets.suggestion 
FROM portfolio_products
JOIN products ON products.id = portfolio_products.product_id
JOIN product_assets ON product_assets.product_id = products.id
JOIN x_assets ON x_assets.id = product_assets.x_assets_id
LEFT JOIN y_assets ON y_assets.id = product_assets.y_assets_id
JOIN user_assets ON (user_assets.x_assets_id = x.id OR 
user_assets.y_assets_id = y.id)
WHERE portfolio_products.portfolio_id = identifier;
$$;`
```

Or something like that per asset type table

```
`create or replace function fetch_x(identifier int)
returns setof record language sql as $$
SELECT products.id as product_id, x_assets.*, user_assets.suggestion 
FROM portfolio_products
JOIN products ON products.id = portfolio_products.product_id
JOIN product_assets ON product_assets.product_id = products.id
JOIN x_assets ON x_assets.id = product_assets.x_assets_id
JOIN user_assets ON user_assets.x_assets_id = x_assets.id
WHERE portfolio_products.portfolio_id = identifier;
$$;`
```

Both are working and are fast, currently, but I kind of doubt they'd be ideal in the long run...

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: I have added the associated queries and version.

Comment: This sound familiar, have you posted it elsewhere

Comment: No, I haven't...